# How to create Spark/Scala project in IntelliJ IDEA (fails to resolve dependencies in build.sbt)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to build and run a Scala/Spark project in IntelliJ IDEA.

I have added `org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.0.0` in global libraries and my `build.sbt` looks like below.

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0"
```

I still get an error that says

> unknown artifact. unable to resolve or indexed

under `spark-sql`.

When tried to build the project the error was

> Error:(19, 26) not found: type sqlContext, val sqlContext = new sqlContext(sc)

I have no idea what the problem could be. How to create a Spark/Scala project in IntelliJ IDEA?

**Update**:
Following the suggestions I updated the code to use `Spark Session`, but it still unable to read a csv file. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

```
 val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Spark example")
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some value")
.getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val testdf = spark.read.csv("/Users/H/Desktop/S_CR_IP_H.dat")
testdf.show()  //it doesn't show anything 
//pdf.select("DATE_KEY").show()
```

Comment: Did you invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: you are trying to read dat files to csv, how is that possible? can I see sample of your dat file?

Comment: _"it still unable to read a csv file."_ that's another issue than the initial one of not being able to create a project, isn't it? If so, you should see the other questions here or ask one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql should upper case letters as below

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

`SQLContext` is deprecated for newer versions of spark so I would suggest you to use `SparkSession`

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testings").getOrCreate 
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
```

If you want to set the `master` through your code instead of from `spark-submit` command then you can set `.master` as well (you can set `configs` too)

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testings").master("local").config("configuration key", "configuration value").getOrCreate 
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
```

**Update**

Looking at your sample data

```
DATE|PID|TYPE
8/03/2017|10199786|O
```

and testing your code

```
val testdf = spark.read.csv("/Users/H/Desktop/S_CR_IP_H.dat")
testdf.show()
```

I had output as

```
+--------------------+
|                 _c0|
+--------------------+
|       DATE|PID|TYPE|
|8/03/2017|10199786|O|
+--------------------+
```

Now adding `.option` for `delimiter` and `header` as

```
val testdf2 = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").option("header", true).csv("/Users/H/Desktop/S_CR_IP_H.dat")
testdf2.show()
```

Output was

```
+---------+--------+----+
|     DATE|     PID|TYPE|
+---------+--------+----+
|8/03/2017|10199786|   O|
+---------+--------+----+
```

**Note**: I have used `.master("local")` for `SparkSession` object

Comment: can I see some sample lines of your dat file `S_CR_IP_H.dat`? Also check if the absolute path `/Users/H/Desktop/S_CR_IP_H.dat` is correct.

Comment: It's like this first line: "DATE|PID|TYPE"
second line: "8/03/2017|10199786|O" and followed by more lines of data

Answer (score 1):

(That should really be part of the Spark official documentation)

Replace the following from your configuration in `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0"
```

with the following:

```
// the latest Scala version that is compatible with Spark
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

// Few changes here
// 1. Use double %% so you don't have to worry about Scala version
// 2. I doubt you need spark-core dependency
// 3. Use the latest Spark version
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
```

Don't worry about IntelliJ IDEA telling you the following:

> unknown artifact. unable to resolve or indexed

It's just something you have to live with and the only solution I could find is to...accept the annoyance.

> val sqlContext = new sqlContext(sc)

The real type is [SQLContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext), but as the scaladoc says:

> As of Spark 2.0, this is replaced by `SparkSession`. However, we are keeping the class here for backward compatibility.

Please use [SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) instead.

> The entry point to programming Spark with the Dataset and DataFrame API.

See the Spark official documentation to read on SparkSession and other goodies. Start from [Getting Started](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#getting-started). *Have fun!*

Comment: One more silly question: if I change to scalaVersion := "2.11.11", I'd need to add that in Global Libraries, right? Is that all the places that need to update it?

Comment: @user4046073 You are **not** supposed to do any changes in IntelliJ IDEA directly, but only through `build.sbt`. When you change the file (and save it), you should see **Enable Auto-Import** link in the top-right corner. Click it to reload your IDEA. You could reload IDEA to make sure you've got all loaded (since I don't see what you're doing that's recommended actually).